# How to change the display style of iframe from none to block:

Tags: jquery, iframe, accordion, show-hide

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
            $(function() {
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion({     
                    collapsible: true,
                    heightStyle: "content",
                    animate: {        
                        duration: 200,        
                        down: {            
                            easing: "easeOutBounce",            
                            duration: 1000        
                        }    
                    }
                });  
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion" style="width: 240px; height: 400px;">
            <h3>Rig Counts</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I1" id="I1" src="https://amazon.com" frameborder="0"  width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no">
                </iframe>   
            </div>
            <h3>Lost Time</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I2" id="I2" src="http://ebay.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
            </div>
            <h3>Rate Of Penetration</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I3" id="I3" src="https://yahoo.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>   
            </div>
            <h3>No Of Incident</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I4" id="I4" src="https://google.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no">
                </iframe>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to enforce iframe to show once the user click over the (h3) tab in the jquery accordion div. (for some reason, my real surce links are hidden and not showing. Yes for these dummy links (amazon, health and others are showing but in my real links they are hidden)?

Comment: we need your assistance.

Comment: So you only want to load the content of iframe when its panel is shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if are trying to load the Iframe only when its panel is show then try this

**http://jsfiddle.net/B4JGe/**

**HTML**
note that I'm setting iframe src in custom attribute to prevent loading it on page load

```
 <div id="accordion" style="width: 240px; height: 400px;">
            <h3>Rig Counts</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I1" id="I1" data-src="http://placehold.it/200&text=1" frameborder="0"  width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no">
                </iframe>   
            </div>
            <h3>Lost Time</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I2" id="I2" data-src="http://placehold.it/200&text=2" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
            </div>
            <h3>Rate Of Penetration</h3>
            <div style="width: 238px; height: 270px;">
                <iframe name="I3" id="I3" data-src="http://placehold.it/200&text=3" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>   
            </div>

        </div>
```

**JS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

            function showIframe(panel){
                $('iframe', panel).each(function(){
                    var iframe = $(this);
                    if(  iframe.attr('src')==undefined ) iframe.attr('src', iframe.data('src') );
                });
            };
            $(function() {
                // show first
                showIframe( $('#accordion div').eq(0)  );

                $( "#accordion" ).accordion({     
                    collapsible: true,
                    heightStyle: "content",
                    animate: {        
                        duration: 200,        
                        down: {            
                            easing: "easeOutBounce",            
                            duration: 1000        
                        }    

                    },
                     beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
                            // show iframes before panel to be activated
                            showIframe(ui.newPanel);
                     }
                });  
            }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: it is working here, what browser u using? did you modify it? did you check JSfiddle ?

Comment: you are right, it is working fine in the JSfiddle, but I don't know why not working in my page. actually, inside my accordions is a multiple charts from one source, but what is working only the active tab. I don’t know why. I thought the problem coming because the iframe is hidden in the jquery, but it seems it is not. One more thing that when I remove the script all charts are showing in my webpage one after one.

Comment: What I did that I added a script that refresh the iframe anytime the user click over any tab, and this work fine with me, but what I need is to have a permanent solution for this problem.

Comment: @Khalil I need a demo of that issue to be able to help